# discord.py - /leaderboard completely breaks when someone leaves all servers w/ the bot in it (if they are on the leaderboard)

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making a leveling system for my bot. I noticed that when someone on the leaderboard leaves the server (if they are no longer in any server with my bot in it) the /leaderboard command completely breaks. It just gives me an error saying `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'display_name'`. I believe the issue is (I already said), that member has left every server with my bot in it, so when the bot attempts to get the user's name, it fails. What should I do to address this issue? I've looked on the internet for a solid 30 minutes and **nothing** helped me. Please and thank you. :)

Full code:

```
message_cooldown = {}


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if not message.author.bot:
        # Check if the user is in the cooldown dictionary
        if message.author.id in message_cooldown:
            current_time = time.time()
            last_message_time = message_cooldown[message.author.id]

            # Check if the user's cooldown has expired (0.5 seconds cooldown)
            if current_time - last_message_time < 1.5:
                if log_enabled == True:
                    with open('botlog.log', 'a') as f:
                        t = time.localtime()
                        current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
                        today = date.today()
                        f.write(f'\n{today} {current_time} [INFO] {message.author.name} has sent a message within cooldown, therefore, no xp')
                if debug_mode == True:
                    print(f"Debug: Message sent too fast, not adding XP for user {message.author.name}. Server Name: {message.guild.name}")
                return

        with open('level.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        await update_data(users, message.author, message.guild)
        await add_experience(users, message.author, 4, message.guild)
        await level_up(users, message.author, message.channel, message.guild)
        if debug_mode == True:
            print(f"Debug: 4 XP has been successfully added to user {message.author.name}. Server Name: {message.guild.name}")
            if log_enabled == True:
                with open('botlog.log', 'a') as f:
                    t = time.localtime()
                    today = date.today()
                    current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
                    f.write(f"\n{today} {current_time} [INFO] 4 XP has been successfully added to user {message.author.name}.")


        # Update the last message time for the user
        message_cooldown[message.author.id] = time.time()

        with open('level.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            json.dump(users, f)
    await bot.process_commands(message)


async def update_data(users, user,server):
    if not str(server.id) in users:
        users[str(server.id)] = {}
        if not str(user.id) in users[str(server.id)]:
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)] = {}
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['experience'] = 0
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['level'] = 1
    elif not str(user.id) in users[str(server.id)]:
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)] = {}
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['experience'] = 0
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['level'] = 1
async def add_experience(users, user, exp, server):
  users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['experience'] += exp

async def level_up(users, user, channel, server):
  experience = users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['experience']
  lvl_start = users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['level']
  lvl_end = int(experience ** (1/3.2))
  if str(user.guild.id) != '757383943116030074':
    if lvl_start < lvl_end:
      embed = discord.Embed(title=f" Level up!", description="{} has leveled up to **Level {}!**".format(user.mention, lvl_end), color=discord.Colour.green())
      await channel.send(embed=embed)
      users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['level'] = lvl_end
      if debug_mode == True:
        print(f"Debug: {user.name} has leveled up to  Level {lvl_end}!")
        if log_enabled == True:
            with open('botlog.log', 'a') as f:
                t = time.localtime()
                today = date.today()
                current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
                f.write(f"\n{today} {current_time} [INFO] {user.name} has leveled up to Level {lvl_end}!")

@bot.tree.command(name='level', description='View a users level.')
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members = True)
async def ban(ctx,member: discord.Member = None):
    if not member:
            # specify the encoding as utf-8 when opening the file
            with open('level.json','r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                users = json.load(f)
            lvl = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(ctx.user.id)]['level']
            exp = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(ctx.user.id)]['experience']
            current_exp = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(ctx.user.id)]['experience']
            current_lvl = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(ctx.user.id)]['level']
            next_exp = (current_lvl + 1) ** 3.2
            missing_exp = int(next_exp - current_exp)
            messages_sent = int(exp // 4)

            embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Level {} '.format(lvl), description = f"{exp} XP " ,color = discord.Color.green())
            embed.add_field(name="XP until Next Level", value=f"{missing_exp} XP")
            embed.add_field(name="Total Messages Sent", value=f"{messages_sent} Messages", inline=False)
            embed.set_author(name=f"User: {ctx.user.name}\nServer: {ctx.guild.name}", url=ctx.user.avatar)
            embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.user.avatar)
            embed.set_footer(text=f"User ID: {ctx.user.id} | Server ID: {ctx.guild.id}")
            await ctx.response.send_message(embed = embed)
            if debug_mode == True:
                print(f"Debug: {ctx.user.name} checked their own level")
            if log_enabled == True:
                with open('botlog.log', 'a') as f:
                    t = time.localtime()
                    current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
                    today = date.today()
                    f.write(f"\n{today} {current_time} [INFO] {ctx.user.name} checked their own level")
    else:
        # specify the encoding as utf-8 when opening the file
        with open('level.json','r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        lvl = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(member.id)]['level']
        exp = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(member.id)]['experience']
        current_exp = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(member.id)]['experience']
        current_lvl = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(member.id)]['level']
        messages_sent = int(exp // 4)
        next_exp = (current_lvl + 1) ** 3.2
        missing_exp = int(next_exp - current_exp)

        embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Level {} '.format(lvl), description = f"{exp} XP " ,color = discord.Color.green())
        embed.add_field(name="XP until Next Level", value=f"{missing_exp} XP")
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar)
        embed.add_field(name="Total Messages Sent", value=f"{messages_sent} Messages", inline=False)
        embed.set_author(name=f"User: {member.name}\nServer: {ctx.guild.name}", url=ctx.user.avatar)
        embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested User ID: {member.id} | Sender ID: {ctx.user.id} | Server ID: {ctx.guild.id}")
        if debug_mode == True:
            print(f"Debug: {ctx.user.name} viewed {member}'s level")
        if log_enabled == True:
            with open('botlog.log', 'a') as f:
                today = date.today()
                t = time.localtime()
                current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
                f.write(f"\n{today} {current_time} [INFO] {ctx.user.name} viewed {member}'s level")

        await ctx.response.send_message(embed = embed)

@bot.tree.command(name="leaderboard", description="View the servers leaderboard. (Levels)")
async def hello(ctx: discord.Interaction):
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Leaderboard for {ctx.guild.name}", color=discord.Colour.blurple())
    with open('level.json', 'r') as file:
        data = json.load(file)
    data = data[str(ctx.guild.id)]
    sorted_data = sorted(data.items(), key = lambda item:item[1]['experience'], reverse=True)
    for pos, (id, bal) in enumerate(sorted_data):
        member = ctx.guild.get_member(int(id))
        embed.add_field(name=f"{pos+1} - {member.display_name} (@{member.name})", value=f"**Level {bal['level']}**\n{bal['experience']} XP", inline=False)
        embed.set_footer(text="Pro tip: Use /level [user] to view more specific information about that member")
        if pos+1 > 9:
            break 
    await ctx.response.send_message(embed=embed)
    if debug_mode == True:
        print(f"Debug: {ctx.user.name} viewed {ctx.guild.name}'s leaderboard")
        if log_enabled == True:
            with open('botlog.log', 'a') as f:
                today = date.today()
                t = time.localtime()
                current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
                f.write(f"\n{today} {current_time} [INFO] {ctx.user.name} viewed a servers leaderboard")
```

Main focus:

```
@bot.tree.command(name="leaderboard", description="View the servers leaderboard. (Levels)")
async def hello(ctx: discord.Interaction):
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Leaderboard for {ctx.guild.name}", color=discord.Colour.blurple())
    with open('level.json', 'r') as file:
        data = json.load(file)
    data = data[str(ctx.guild.id)]
    sorted_data = sorted(data.items(), key = lambda item:item[1]['experience'], reverse=True)
    for pos, (id, bal) in enumerate(sorted_data):
        member = ctx.guild.get_member(int(id))
        embed.add_field(name=f"{pos+1} - {member.display_name} (@{member.name})", value=f"**Level {bal['level']}**\n{bal['experience']} XP", inline=False)
        embed.set_footer(text="Pro tip: Use /level [user] to view more specific information about that member")
        if pos+1 > 9:
            break 
    await ctx.response.send_message(embed=embed)
    if debug_mode == True:
        print(f"Debug: {ctx.user.name} viewed {ctx.guild.name}'s leaderboard")
        if log_enabled == True:
            with open('botlog.log', 'a') as f:
                today = date.today()
                t = time.localtime()
                current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
                f.write(f"\n{today} {current_time} [INFO] {ctx.user.name} viewed a servers leaderboard")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'display_name'

indicates that somewhere in your code, you are trying to access `None.display_name`. The `display_name` is only accessed in this line in your code, so that must be the culprit -- as you say:

```py
embed.add_field(name=f"{pos+1} - {member.display_name} (@{member.name})", value=f"**Level {bal['level']}**\n{bal['experience']} XP", inline=False)
```

How you deal with it depends on what behaviour you actually want in the case where `member` is `None`. But you can check for it using a check like this:

```py
 for pos, (id, bal) in enumerate(sorted_data):
        member = ctx.guild.get_member(int(id))
        if member is None:
            continue # This skips the current member
        else:
            embed.add_field(name=f"{pos+1} - {member.display_name} (@{member.name})", value=f"**Level {bal['level']}**\n{bal['experience']} XP", inline=False)
            embed.set_footer(text="Pro tip: Use /level [user] to view more specific information about that member")
            if pos+1 > 9:
                break
```

Comment: I would consider adding the if pos thing to the none thing too, because if you don't, it goes over 10, and I don't want that happening. (I alr did)